# dropdown event is not firing in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

```
protected void dd_State_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataView dv_City = dt_City.DefaultView;

    dv_City.RowFilter = "StateID='" + dd_State.SelectedValue + "'";
    dv_City.Sort = "DistrictName";

    dd_City.DataSource = dv_City;
    dd_City.DataTextField = "DistrictName";
    dd_City.DataValueField = "DistrictId";
    dd_City.DataBind();

    dd_City.Items.Insert(0, "--Select City--");
}
```

I have set `autopostback` to  true and enable `viewstate` to true. Still while debugging it would not go to dropdown selected index. The event does not fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting

```
ViewStateMode="Enabled"
```

For more info, check [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1317586.aspx?SelectedIndexChanged%20event%20of%20dropDownList%20not%20firing) and [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c1f66568-1ece-483c-969c-6dc66ea77c49/dropdownlist-selectedindexchanged-not-firing?forum=winformsdesigner).